# http request with cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a request with javascript but the cookie part seem to be not working. Code I'm using is below.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     <!--
        function SendReq(){
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var path="http://192.168.186.131/hello.html";
            request.onreadystatechange=state_change;

            request.open("GET", path, true);
            request.withCredentials = true;
            document.cookie="sessionid=d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249";
            request.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            request.setRequestHeader("Cookie",document.cookie);
            request.setRequestHeader("Accept-encoding",'deflate');

            request.send(null);
                function state_change(){
                if (request.readyState==4){
                    alert('ready');
                    if (request.status==200){
                       alert('ok');
                    }
                else{
                alert("Problem retrieving XML data");
                }
              }
            }
     }
  </script>
```

What could be the issue here? Are there better ways to get this done?

Comment: No need of sending cookie header, browser sends it automatically just make sure document.cookie has a valid value.

Comment: Is the domain that you're sending the ajax call to the same domain as the web page you're running from?  I ask because you cannot control cookies for any other domain than the one the web page was loaded from.  You can't set the cookie header yourself (the browser will override anything you set) and you can't set cookies for a cross-origin domain.